# $\text{Log}_2$ of set functors

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given a functor $T: \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ is there a way to understand if it is of the form $2^G$ for a functor $G: \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$?

I am looking for a condition like  *if such a $G$ exists then it must be...*

My fear is that this might be linked to [Easton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem).

---

Note: Everything is covariant here.

Comment: So you want $T$ to be literally equal, not just naturally isomorphic, to $\mathcal P\circ G$.  That looks strange to me.

Comment: The problem is a bit confusing as stated. Is $2^G$ supposed to be covariant or contravariant? Put differently, do you want $P$ to be the covariant or contravariant power set functor (beware: the covariant power set functor does not take values in the category of Boolean algebras)?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, isomorphic is ok.

Comment: @ToddTrimble covariant.

Comment: So just to be clear: you want both $T$ and $G$ to be covariant? If so, then what is the *covariant* power set functor $P: Set \to Bool$ that you refer to? (There isn't any that I know of.)

Comment: Can't you associate to a set the set of its parts and to a function $f: A \to B$ the function $\mathcal{P}(f)(C) = \{f(x) | c \in C \}$ for all $C \in \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: Yes, but that is not a Boolean algebra map.

Comment: Oh I see your point now.